# How to extract values from JSON request in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, performance, jmeter

I need to extract the specific tags (email and type) from my JSON request in JMeter. Below is a sample request.  Note: I have found multiple extractors for extracting values from the response but I need it for the request:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "externalId": "001",
      "name":{  
         "givenName":"002",
         "familyName":"003",
         "middleName":"004",
         "honorificPrefix":"Mr",
         "honorificSuffix":"LL.D"
      },    
    "emails": [
      {
        "value": "005",
        "type": "work",
        "primary": true
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense, if you're sending the request you "know" this email "value" and "type" attributes values

Just in case I don't know the specific of your test (i.e. you're getting this JSON from external source), you can extract the values from the [HTTP Request sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
def email = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()).customer.emails.first()
vars.put('value', email.value)
vars.put('type', email.type)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T
we are able to extract the values from Request except for immediate attributes, In the above example we need to capture the externalId value. Can you please help us to the same. We tried below script 'def rawData1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()).customer.first();
vars.put('rawData1', rawData1.externalId);
log.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + vars.get("rawData1") + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");'